# XSLT 2.0 - Extract attribute and value from paramter(XML)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT 2.0 and sending below input in parameter.

```
> &lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?&gt;
> 
> &lt;map&gt;
> 
>   &lt;entry key="26840413"&gt;1&lt;/entry&gt;
> 
>   &lt;entry key="26840222"&gt;2&lt;/entry&gt;
> 
> &lt;/map&gt;
```

In xstl i have to extract the value of key attribute and value. I tried

```
 <xsl:template name="data">
      <xsl:value-of select="$paramxml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="myinput" >
    <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
</xsl:variable>

<test><xsl:value-of select="$myinput/map/entry[@key = '26840413']/></test>
```

But its giving blank value. Any suggestions

Comment: It is important to tell us which XSLT 2 processor you use and how exactly you pass in the parameter. If you really pass in a string of XML then, in XSLT 3, you could use `parse-xml($paramxml)` or you would need to use a similar extension function proprietary to your XSLT 2 processor.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..i am using mule xslt processor https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/1.2/xml-xslt . Is there similar extension of parse-xml in 2.0?

Comment: I think its working for me now...I used parse-xml($items)/map/entry/[@key]

Comment: Good, if `parse-xml` is working then under the hood you seem to have an XSLT 3 processor or an XSLT 2 processor supporting that XPath 3 function. Just forget about the `disable-output-escaping` stuff, that doesn't help.